Does serverless SQL pool approach of the Azure synapse analytics provide a SQL db on the endpoint?
I have data in azure data lake gen2 parquet files.
Using Azure synapse analytics I have created SQL pool. Then, via linked service I'm connecting to parquet file. Then, I have created multiple views that do select * from OPENROWSET... from couple of parquet files.
I can use the SQL endpoint in a reporting tool like Power BI to fetch the data from the above views.
Question:
What is the purpose of the SQL endpoint? Does it have a SQL database which could hold the data from the view? Or does SQL endpoint only represent a resource to query the data from parquet file?


Does it have a SQL database which could hold the data from the view? Or does SQL endpoint only represent a resource to query the data from parquet file?

According to MS document in serverless SQL pool

tables are not supported. Serverless SQL pool can query only external tables that reference data stored in Azure Data Lake storage or Dataverse.

You can create views over external tables, the queries with the OPENROWSET function, and other views. Views can use query language elements that are available in serverless model. That means views can only represent a resource to query the data from external table hat reference data stored in Azure Data Lake storage or Dataverse.
So, the serverless SQL endpoint doesn't store the data itself, it allows you to query external data like Parquet files dynamically, providing real-time access without creating physical SQL tables in your pool. You can use view to query the data using views as shown below:

If you want to store the data without using external data sources you can use dedicated SQL pool in synapse.
